# Invalid or incomplete statement. expected one of the following BITMAPCONTEXTDICRETIORY... SQL linter pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I think i have a problem with my set up on pycharm.

I run this query inside a .sql file (query is working well):

```
CREATE TABLE "migrations" (
  "filename" VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "migration_date" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But i got linter error from pycharm :
[image]

I tried to change settings :
Settings -> Code style -> SQL -> General -> preview dialect -> PostgreSQL

But i still got the linter error, do you have any idea from what it could come ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
Probably, you use the Database Navigator plugin.

I uninstalled it, and the error disappeared.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For me it was enough to deactivate the Database Navigator plugin and restart Rider.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. It turns out I didn't set up my database connection[image]

Once I made the proper connection the error goes away

[image]

To make the connection, click on the drop down manual and select the database (for me its recipes)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the h2 URL  `~/mydb` and the table name were matching. Due to this, the application was either failing or not showing the tables I created through the schema.sql file.

make sure the below `~/practice` part is not the same value as your table name:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/practice;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after I installed and then uninstalled Database Navigator plugin. IDEA just stopped to recognize *.sql files and autocompletion or code formatting didn't work.
Go to: File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Recognized File Types
Find in the list of File Types "SQL" and check if you have in File name patterns section "*.sql". If not - add it.
I suppose that uninstallation of Database Navigator removes "*.sql" file pattern as a revenge.